# How can I tell a infopath XML datasource is connecting to which list?

Tags: infopath

I am working on a SP2010 on-premise. I am new here and the environment is not developed by me. In one of InfoPath form code behind, it is trying to update a list with a datasoruce. Part of code is like:

```
    private void AddEntry(string action, string value)
    {
        XPathNavigator parentNode = this.CreateNavigator();
        string dataSourceName = "unknownXML";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<Method ID=\"{0}\" Cmd=\"{1}\">", 1, "New");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Field Name=\"Title\">{0}</Field>", GetControlAsXPathNavigator(parentNode, "/my:Report/my:ReportID").Value);
        sb.AppendFormat("<Field Name=\"Action\">{0}</Field>", action);
        sb.AppendFormat("<Field Name=\"Value\">{0}</Field>", value), GetControlAsXPathNavigator(parentNode, "/my:Report/my:LoggedInUserID").Value);
        sb.AppendFormat("</Method>");
        XmlDocument methodXML = new XmlDocument();
        methodXML.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
        XPathNavigator secDSNav = DataSources[dataSourceName].CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator batchNav = Utilities.DeleteNilTagFromXPathNavigator(secDSNav.SelectSingleNode("/Batch", NamespaceManager));
        batchNav.AppendChild(methodXML.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator());
    }
```

I checked the InfoPath > Data Connections. I can find "unknownXML". It is a XML file with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
        <Field Name='Name'></Field>
        <Field Name="Email"></Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

According to the "field name" defined in above code, it is trying to add item to one of list. However we have many list have those fields. How can I find which list it is adding to?